# Can I make a call to datacontext class asynchronously in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Here I am trying to invoke `DbContext` object asynchronously from my method. Does it make any performance impact? I know that Entity Framework is not thread safe.

```
private async Task HasPreviousRecords(long passengerid, long segmentid, short legnumber, long inventoryLegid, string unitdesignator)
{
    var defaultTime = Convert.ToDateTime("9999-12-31 00:00:00.000");
    var records = _baseContext.PassengerJourneyLegVersions.Select(s => s).Where(s =>
                         s.VersionEndUTC != defaultTime &&
                         s.LiftStatus.Equals(1) &&
                         s.UnitDesignator != string.Empty &&
                         s.InventoryLegID.Equals(inventoryLegid) &&
                         s.LegNumber.Equals(legnumber) &&
                         s.SegmentID.Equals(segmentid) &&
                         s.PassengerID.Equals(passengerid)).ToList().OrderByDescending(s => s.VersionStartUTC).FirstOrDefault();

    if (records != null)
    {
        if (unitdesignator != records.UnitDesignator)
        {
            var passengerJourneryLeg = new PassengerJourneryLeg()
                    {
                        InventoryLegid = Convert.ToInt32(inventoryLegid),
                        Legnumber = Convert.ToInt32(legnumber),
                        Passengerid = Convert.ToInt32(passengerid),
                        Segmentid = Convert.ToInt32(segmentid)
                    };
            await PushMessageToQueue(passengerJourneryLeg);
        }
    }
}
```

The context class has singleton lifetime of dependency.

Comment: Async has nothing to do with thread safety. And this is _HORRIBLY_ inefficient: `.ToList().OrderByDescending(s => s.VersionStartUTC).FirstOrDefault();` Finally, async will typically mean that there is a slight performance impact in terms of raw latency, but overall throughput for your application will increase dramatically. That said, your problem is most likely NOT async vs sync. It looks like a badly written EF query.

Comment: What "invoke" are you talking about? Besides David's advice, can you benchmark your app with and without async?

Comment: @DavidL can you specific that?

Comment: @JintoJohn sure, done.

Comment: @JintoJohn Not only is EF not Thread safe, it is not concurrent safe. Using the same Context in multiple Task (but same thread) will fail.

Comment: @DavidL if multiple thread use same context ,which may have an impact on performance right ?.Please correct me if I am  wrong

Comment: @JintoJohn Do not use the same context in multiple Threads, you can use the DB context factory for this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor). Create a new context each time you need one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a common misconception that asynchronous operations will perform "faster", or have lower latency than synchronous operations. This is incorrect. Async calls will typically introduce a tiny (sometimes immeasurable) amount of additional latency due to the creation of the async state machine and the cost of queueing up continuations.

That said, what you gain from an asynchronous I/O in your application is significant improvements in *throughput*. By not tying up threads with blocking I/O calls, those threads are now free to do more work, leading to greater throughput for your application.

Entity Framework Core provides async variants of common deferred execution methods that must be awaited (`ToListAsync` vs `ToList` or `FirstOrDefaultAsync` vs `FirstOrDefault`) and should be used when switching to async.

In addition, when querying your context, you want to avoid projecting the entire collection into memory when you only need one record. The following snippet adds several optimizations:

- It switches from sync to async
- It removes the unnecessary .Select call
- It stops projecting the entire collection in memory and executes a `select top 1` query on the database side instead

```
private async Task HasPreviousRecords(long passengerid, long segmentid, short legnumber, long inventoryLegid, string unitdesignator)
{
    var defaultTime = Convert.ToDateTime("9999-12-31 00:00:00.000");
    var records = await _baseContext.PassengerJourneyLegVersions
        .Where(s =>
                 s.VersionEndUTC != defaultTime &&
                 s.LiftStatus.Equals(1) &&
                 s.UnitDesignator != string.Empty &&
                 s.InventoryLegID.Equals(inventoryLegid) &&
                 s.LegNumber.Equals(legnumber) &&
                 s.SegmentID.Equals(segmentid) &&
                 s.PassengerID.Equals(passengerid))
        .OrderByDescending(s => s.VersionStartUTC)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    
    if (records != null)
    {
        if (unitdesignator != records.UnitDesignator)
        {
            var passengerJourneryLeg = new PassengerJourneryLeg()
            {
                InventoryLegid = Convert.ToInt32(inventoryLegid),
                Legnumber = Convert.ToInt32(legnumber),
                Passengerid = Convert.ToInt32(passengerid),
                Segmentid = Convert.ToInt32(segmentid)
            };
            await PushMessageToQueue(passengerJourneryLeg);
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that DbContext absolutely should NOT be a singleton.  It should be Scoped or Transient and should be disposed at the end of every context usage.

Comment: if multiple thread use same context ,which may have an impact on performance right ?.Please correct me if I am  wrong

Comment: It isn't just performance. It will actually throw an exception if you try to reuse the same dbcontext concurrently with async operations. You absolutely should use a new async context once per operations OR you must wait until one operation completes before starting the next operation. A singleton db context does neither of these.

Answer (score 1):

It's OK to use an EF context in an asynchronous method but you need to ensure that any methods that may run in parallel are not using the same context.